# How to make 3D plots in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, mplot3d

This is the MATLAB version of the 3D plotting code:
EDIT:
This is the current code:

```
        plt.figure(2)
        fig_b = Axes3D(fig2)
        xx2 = np.arange(0, L+h_grid*L, h_grid*L)
        yy2 = np.arange(-b, b+h_grid*b, h_grid*b)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(xx2, yy2)
        W = np.zeros((41,21), float)
        mx = len(xx2)*len(yy2)
        X = np.reshape(X, (1, mx))
        Y = np.reshape(Y, (1, mx))
        W = np.reshape(W, (1, mx))
        for j in range(0, mx):
            W[0][j] = np.sin(np.pi*X[0][j]/L)
        surf = fig_b.plot_surface(X, Y, W, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0, antialiased=False) # This is the line number 168
        plt.xlabel('x')
        plt.ylabel('y')
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nonhomog.py", line 247, in <module>
    main()
  File "nonhomog.py", line 245, in main
    nonhomog(nu)
  File "nonhomog.py", line 168, in nonhomog
    surf = fig_b.plot_surface(X, Y, W, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 618, in plot_surface
    polyc = art3d.Poly3DCollection(polys, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 290, in __init__
    PolyCollection.__init__(self, verts, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/collections.py", line 668, in __init__
    self.set_verts(verts, closed)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 312, in set_verts
    self.get_vector(verts)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 305, in get_vector
    xs, ys, zs = zip(*points)
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Comment: It would help if you would show all your code, including the `matplotlib` and `numpy` imports.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the pastebin code you showed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After setting up the mesh grid for X and Y, you need to come up with a grid for Z values.

The way I currently do this in my code is:

```
# [ (x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2), ... (xN, yN, zN) ]
all_vals = ...
# (x1, x2, ... xN) , (y1, y2, ... yN) , (z1, z2, ... zN)
all_xvals, all_yvals, all_zvals = zip(*all_vals)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xvals, yvals)
# This is the part you want:
Z1 = np.zeros(X.shape, float)
for (x, y, z) in all_vals:
    x = find_in_sorted_list(x, xvals)
    y = find_in_sorted_list(y, yvals)
    Z1[y,x] = z    
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z1, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet,
        linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
plt.xlabel('Blur standard deviation')  
plt.ylabel('JPEG quality')
ax.w_zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.w_zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.03f'))    
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)    
plt.show()
```

This gives me a plot that looks like this:

[image: surf]

I've saved it as a file, but when you call `plt.show()`, you get an interactive window where you can change the viewpoint to anything you want.

Comment: Thanks! Looks very promising. Can you see my edits to my original question, please? I have added there something. I get this error message:  
"ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack"
What's wrong with my new code?

Comment: The problem may be related to the fact that you're reshaping your grids as 1D arrays (1 row, N columns).  They should be 2D arrays.  Have a closer look at my code -- look at how Z1 is initialized, and how it is populated with values.

Comment: Thanks! I added these lines: X = np.reshape(X, (41, 21))
            Y = np.reshape(Y, (41, 21))
            W = np.reshape(W, (41, 21))
after the for loop of my current code and now it works like a dream.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it works for you.  I'm not sure if you need to reshape X and Y -- since they were made using meshgrid, they are probably of that shape already.

Comment: I have to access X and Y using only one argument: X(j), Y(j). That is why I think reshaping is necessary.

Comment: @misha, I'm having trouble making your sample work. Can you fix it so that runs on just a example data and doesn't depend on that find_in_sorted_list function (yours?). I want to do something similar but I'm having trouble understanding the Z format.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong? You are trying to make a non-number negative.
In other words: AxesSubplot (whatever that is) doesn't implement the unary - operator.

So, that code can not reasonably be "what you have done", as you don't even define `b` in that code, yet it exists and is of some custom type called `AxesSubplot`. If you explain what AxesSubplot is, then that would help. Try including code that actually demonstrates the problem, if possible.

Edit:
As DSM points out, you overwrite your b variable.
The problem is that you are stuck in "maths mode" and use non-descriptive variable names like "a", "b" and "M". Use longer descriptive names instead.

Instead of:

```
 a = fig.add_subplot(2,2,i)
 b = fig2.add_subplot(2,2,i)
```

do:

```
 x_subplot = fig.add_subplot(2,2,i)
 y_subplot = fig2.add_subplot(2,2,i)
```

Or something like that (I'm not sure what the variable actually *is*, so that's just an example).

Comment: @user569474: No it's not. It's an AxesSubplot. The error clearly states this. It is *not* a float.

Comment: @user569474: see line 107 of your pastebin code, b = fig2.add_subplot(2,2,i), which overwrites your b= 0.5 assignment.  As pointed out above, error messages aren't always right, but they're usually the best place to start.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, one flaw was that there were two different things with a same name b.